# How can i insert data into a log table after update using triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am new to triggers and i am trying to insert data into a log table after the Alumns table was updated.

```
| Alumn_ID (PK) | Name   |  Courses    | Favourite_Course
      1             Peter       5                3

| Log_ID | Alumn_ID |   Note  
     1          1       Number of courses was changed
```

For some reason it is not letting me insert the Alumn ID and the trigger doesn't work, also i can't find how to insert the log id as identity

```
ALTER TRIGGER [LOG]
ON ALUMNS
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Note VARCHAR(50)

DECLARE @Alumn_ID varchar;
SELECT @Alumn_ID= INSERTED.Alumn_ID FROM INSERTED

IF UPDATE(Name)
BEGIN
SET @Note = 'Updated Name'
END


INSERT INTO Alumn_Log (Log_ID, Note)
VALUES (@Alumn_ID, '@Alumn')
END
```

After that i am trying to modify the name to see if the trigger works and i get the next error:

ERROR:

No row was updated

The data in row 1 was not commited.
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
Error Message: instruction INSERT is in conflict with restriction FOREIGN KEY "FK_ALUMN_LOG_ALUMN_ID". 
The conflict has appeared in database "SCHOOL", table "dbo.ALUMNS", Column "ALUMN_ID."
Instruction ended.

Correct the errors and retry or press ESC to cancel the change(s).

Comment: Firstly, you've made the usual beginners mistake of thinking that `INSERTED` has only one record. Everyone does it. What does "not letting me insert the Alumn ID and the trigger doesn't work" mean. Can you describe, with code and error messages, what you are doing and in what way it doesn't work. Please edit your question as this is key to the question

Comment: is says something about a problem with foreing key, it does nothing, doesn't let me update any row, is the trigger well written?

Comment: Please edit your question and actually post the error. No the trigger is not well written. It will crash if you insert or update more than one row

Comment: add your error and table structure in the question, if possible

Comment: I see  that out of eight questions with good answers, you have not marked _any_ as answered. Please consider posting reasonable questions and marking answers correctly.

Comment: updated with error, sorry i am new in this, i am going to mark the past question as answered since they are thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the trigger doesn't work because `id` has more than one character.

I don't know what `@Note` is supposed to be doing, because it is not being used.  So, your logic can be reduced to:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [LOG] ON ALUMNS AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Alumn_Log (Log_ID, Note)
        SELECT i.Alumn_ID, '@Alumn'
        FROM inserted i;
END;
```